# Filter to exclude Columns

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I am not sure why this is not working. In theory this should work, as I know it works for other excels I have.

[Switch Formula not working for All Countries option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfLIj.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Shea

Comment: I have it now working to include the country column but I cannot get it to filter by country

Comment: Share a sample gs link here.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A1:S},"Select Col"&TEXTJOIN(",Col" , 1,IFERROR(MATCH(W1:Z1,A1:S1,0)))&" Where Col1 = "&U2&" ",0))
```

[This is the file with formula output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rv8cAbNP15vqcDCLf1vQsgvyxw5zB5LibGTD1SQtNKo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Filter function of Google Sheet is much simpler.

> =FILTER('Plan Details'!B5:S100,'Plan Details'!B5:B100=C2)

If you only need specific columns, you can do:

> =FILTER({'Plan Details'!B5:E100,'Plan Details'!S5:S100},'Plan Details'!B5:B100=C2)

Comment: So I used the second option which works but in excel I can use a 'wildcard' by using switch to return all Countries. But the formula doesn't seem to work for that, I have added a screenshot of the switch formula I would use normally